# What's the best way to safely access a shared object in kernel mode in a multiprocessor architecture

Tags: windows, concurrency, kernel, wdm

I've read on The Rootkit Arsenal book(page 269 - https://books.google.co.il/books?id=GAsuwHTquhEC) about kernel synchronization techniques.

According to what I've read, the safest/appropriate way to access a shared object in a multi CPU architecture is to issue a DPC call for every CPU core and spin over the shared object while the "main" core processing the shared object.

I don't really get It why spinning over a shared object and processing on a single cpu core is not enough, can someone explain to me?

Comment: `safest/appropriate way to access a shared object in a multi CPU architecture is to issue a DPC call` - this is absolute nonsense. absolute

Comment: We really need more context here.  My best guess would be that they're talking about the case where you want to manipulate an object *that doesn't belong to you,* in which case it is presumably necessary to ensure that nobody else's code can be running at the same time, including the Windows kernel itself.